# Summation of rows

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am trying to maintain a database for a collection of items. Items and values are read from the collection of files. I want summation of frequency of repeating item in the table.

if i have a table like

```
type   frequency
---------------
bar       10
soap      25
bar       13
```

then I need the table to be

```
type   frequency
---------------
bar       23
soap      25
```

How do I update such table?

I tried

```
SELECT
    type,
    SUM(frequency)
FROM
   MyTable
```

but output is like

```
type    frequency
-----------------
bar       48
```

Comment: Do you really want to `update` the table?  Assuming not, just use `group by` . . .

Comment: i want to update the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a simple `GROUP BY` on your query to tell the aggregate function `SUM()` how to group the data. Without a `GROUP BY` your aggregate function will just sum all of the rows together.

```
UPDATE table t,
(   
    SELECT type, SUM(frequency) as frequency
    FROM table
    GROUP BY type
) t1

SET t.frequency = t1.frequency WHERE t.type = t1.type
```

This is a way you can update the table with a sum of each type.

Your update will cause duplicate entries in the database for every type. A simple fix for this is an alter on the table to add a unique index that will not allow there to be more than one. You have to use `IGNORE` or else it will say you have a duplicate entry

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE table ADD UNIQUE INDEX `my_special_idx` (type, frequency);
```

[**SQL Fiddle Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84441/1)

Comment: Shouldn't the UNIQUE INDEX be just on type?  Otherwise you could insert the same type with a different frequency.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf it shouldn't make a difference since you are already aggregating them together... you can always update the frequency with a new sum.. just cant have a duplicate amount

Comment: Yes, you are aggregating them once, but then you would have to keep re-running it to aggregate them.  If you make the UNIQUE INDEX on type, then they can't re-create duplicates.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf still doesn't matter though because its just a one time thing... once you have removed duplicates all you will be doing is updating the frequency for duplicates

Answer (score 2):

You need `GROUP BY` for aggregate functions.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    type,
    SUM(frequency)
FROM
    MyTable
GROUP BY 
    type
```